# SQL - auto increment withing group inside one table

Tags: php, mysql

is there a way in MySQL to have autoincrement or something similiar in one table?

I want to have ID, SHOP_ID, SHOP_CUSTOMER_ID, NAME

I want ID to be a standard autoincrement and I will use it for all kinds of joins, but I want to display to user the SHOP_CUSTOMER_ID so they have a correct number from 1, not show the ID which could be 912314

Now I do it with php function, but its to slow and sometimes I get duplicate entry errors for key (SHOP_ID, SHOP_CUSTOMER_ID)

Is there a way to use autoincrement in sql?

Comment: I guess you're aware of [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)? If that's the case I struggle to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to have ID auto increment, but also SHOP_CUSTOMER_ID should be incremented within a shop_id, so if its a first insert for shop_id = 5 the SHOP_CUSTOMER_ID should be 1 even though it has ID = 154 (or whatever many rows are inside a table)

Comment: There is a simple workaround. Forget storing the SHOP_CUSTOMER_ID in your database. Just store the first, that is the lowest, ID of this table in the table you have for a shop. The customer id will then be the normal ID minus that lowest ID (plus one) you stored in the shop table.

Comment: Also, you don't even need to store the lowest ID, you can (sub)query it with: `SELECT MIN(ID) FROM mytable WHERE SHOP_ID = ?;`.

Comment: Let me know if I understand correctly, but in this table there will be many of customers and also there is many shops - I don't think storing only the lowest ID helps with anything?

Comment: Yes, my comments were not completely correct. Let's make it simpler, and assume you still want to store the customer id. This id should be an increasing number, starting from 1 for each shop. You can do this when you insert a new row in the table. Given input: <shop id> and <name>, and the insert query: `INSERT INTO <that table> (SHOP_ID, SHOP_CUSTOMER_ID, NAME) VALUES (<shop id>, (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM <that table> WHERE SHOP_ID = <shop id>), <name>);`. So the subquery counts the number of rows, present in the table, for a shop, adds one, and uses that as the value of the customer id.